# how I can start lein ring server in background?

Tags: shell, clojure, leiningen, ring

Now what I do is:

```
$ lein ring server &
```

Then what I see is: [1]+ Stopped lein ring server. Then I'm trying to use:

```
$ fg 1
```

And also see that it's stopped. What do I do wrong and how can I run ring as a background process?

Comment: Yep - it's misprint, sorry. I'm using your variant.

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: $ /bin/bash I think =)
"nohup" in answers below simple and useful - it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lein simply launches a Java process, this answer of course does not apply to ring/leiningen only.

The simplest way might be to use one of the following Linux/UNIX utilities (and some more as well):

- screen
- detachtty
- nohup